# MIMO vs phased antenna in rapidly changing environment

Tags: wireless-networking, antenna

I have not found any good description of MIMO and am most concerned with the input. As I understand it, the inputs from all the antennas are monatored and the one with the best signal is used. In my case, two antennas are circularly polarized and with insufficient directivity to avoid mulitpath signals. They are trying to see thorugh trees which will be blowing in the wind so if MIMO is used, it must be fast enough to adapt. If the antennas are to be phased and used as one, they will be set for maximum directivity. So which is the best way to go?

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia article on [802.11n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009) has a good overview on MIMO, and for in-depth details you can read the standard itself. However, what part of the standard is actually implemented, and how well, depends heavily on the firmware of the router etc., so there's no alternative to trying it out.

That said, MIMO is used for several things:

1) Simultaniously transferring several streams of targets to different peers (doesn't apply for your case).

2) Making sending and receiving directional. (What you mentioned as "the antennas are to be phased and used as one").

3) Taking advantage of multipath transmissions arising from reflections in the environment etc. This will show up in the receiving antenna as multiple packets received from different directions at different times, so the receiver will decode all of the packets and keep the one with the best quality. This is very different from "monitor all antennas and use the one with the best signal".

Your trees very likely won't cause multipath transmissions, so the effect of moving trees will just be varying attenuation of the signal. However, other features in your environment may cause multipath transmission, for example buildings a bit off the direct path between transmitter and receiver.

As for "what is the best way to go", you don't really have much choice: All antennas will already be exploited for directionality, and the environment is the way it is. The only parameters you can really influence is (a) which router hardware you use, (b) the position of the antenna and (c) which antenna you use if the antennas are detachable. None of these have anything to do with MIMO proper.

There are routers that are specifically made for outdoors and have directional antennas, e.g. the [TP-Link CPE210](http://www.tp-link.de/products/details/cat-37_CPE210.html) or the [Ubiquiti Nanostation](https://www.ubnt.com/airmax/nanostationm/). Investing in one of those might make more sense than worrying about MIMO. :-)

Comment: The key information given is  "the receiver will decode all of the packets and keep the one with the best quality." So the advantage of the 2 antennas with 18 dBi gain vs 1 with the aditional directivity that comes with proper phasing is that each antenna will inevitably pick up problem packets as multipath (due to many tall buildings) signal strengths vary, so I think analysis of redundant packets which is only possible with multiple antennas is better than just adding the signals.

Comment: @robeyw: Where did he say that there are many tall buildings? He was just talking about trees. Also, the choice isn't really "2 antennas vs. 1 with directivity". Either you can detach the antennas, and then you can replace them with directional ones if you like (all two of them), or you can't detach them. Or, like in the outdoor routers I mentioned, they already come with directional antennas (two of them). I also have no idea where you got the 18 dBi gain from.